# Android Studio Avd emulator shows a black flickering

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have an issue all of a sudden where I am getting a weird black flickering at the bottom of the screen (as shown in the video below). I had no problem earlier also this happened after I removed `android emulator` and rechecked it (Reinstalled it ) under the setting  `“Tools” ->” SDK Manager” -> “SDK Tools” tab`.

Video Link - https://vimeo.com/manage/videos/739329236

Computer Specs -
I7 - 10750h,
Nvidia 1650 Ti - 4GB,
16 GB Ram,
1 TB SSD (443 GB free)

Also, I have noticed the screen goes most of the part blank when I am not touching the screen.
[image]

Comment: Have you found any solution yet, apart from downgrading the sdk version @stars-tracker

Comment: No not as of yet stopped trying

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I tried giving more memory (4096 RAM) to my emulator and the issue disappeared.

[image: More ram for android emulator]

Comment: I gave 5000MB of RAM, 5000MB of Internal Storage and 1025 MB of VM heap. But still the AVD is flickering.

Answer (score 73):

I had a same issue in my new laptop. I have fixed it by changing one parameter in the emulator's config file.

- Go to `C:\Users\USER_NAME\.android\avd\Pixel_5_API_31.avd}}`
- Edit the `config.ini` file.
- Find the `hw.gpu.mode = auto` and change it to the `hw.gpu.mode = guest` and save the changes.
- Restart the emulator.

Comment: Solved the problem for me on an Intel GPU too (i7-12700H). But instead of "guest" i took "angle_indirect" as i am on windows, which should be a bit better as it is not purely in software inside the guest but also using DirectX. It should have similar performance to "auto" or "host", but without the rendering problems.

Comment: I was using Android API_30, on my Windows10, and this answer worked for me.
thanx

Comment: I was using API level 31 before. Some answers suggested to use API level 30. But after installing, I was getting same flicker issue. So, I tried @Srikar Uppu 's answer and it worked just fine for me

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem recently after create a emulator with API level 33,
Then I've tried to used API level 31 and emulator works normally.

Comment: Ok thanks for letting me know I think maybe its a bug for API 33.

Comment: Same problem here but API 31 (and 32) also flickers for me. All of these are x86_64 but it works if I go back to API 30 that is x86. The operating system goes from nice and modern Android to a UI that looks like it's from 2002 but the graphics are smooth, fast and doesn't flicker :)

Comment: This is not working for me even on API level 31 or even 30

Answer (score 9):

I just installed Android Studio first time for a while and noticed the flickering problem right away. I have NVIDIA GPU which most likely contributes into this problem. In the AVD options inside the Android Studio device manager I tried switching the Graphics setting from automatic to "Software GLES 2.0" and it fixed the flickering. No way using software acceleration is optimal in any way but it could be a workaround until the root cause is fixed.

EDIT: found the issue posted about this behavior confirming it is a GPU driver related issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/246917660

Answer (score 4):

It seems there is a problem with the x86_64 images. If Software GLESS is turned on then the flicker goes away but the graphics are little laggy.
x86 images works well smooth but out-dated.

Answer (score 1):

I just switched to a Pixel 5 with API 33 and it seems to have resolved my flickering problem..

Answer (score 1):

if you have Intel GPU and GeForce GPU. You should launch emulator with Intel GPU  because this problem is related to the GeForce driver. You can try these steps. This solved my problem:

1. Copy emulator path: C:\Users\YOUR_PROFILE\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64
2. (for windows 11) Start/Settings/System/Display/Grafics
3. Find option "add application" and click Browse.
4. Paste emulator path and select "qemu-system-x86_64" then Ok
5. Then select this app and click Parameters and choose GPU Intel(energy saving)
6. Save settings and launch emulator

Comment: Why/how "black flickering" is related to GeForce driver?

Comment: I don't know but this issue described here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/246917660

Comment: You're right, the issue is **described** there but it **doesn't say** it is related to the GeForce driver. Also, "when this one makes problems use another one" is not really a solution, does it?

Comment: may be, but when I launch emulator with my Intel GPU - it work for me and some people too

Answer (score 0):

Same here. After one of the latest Emulator (in SDK tools) updates virtual device with API level 31 or above show same issues. Devices with API level 30 or below work fine.
Tried to completely clean and re-install Studio and Video drivers. No effect.
So since it started right after update i believe it's Emulator component issue.

Comment: You can leave your comment as a reply/comment within the question and not as a standalone answer.